# Pandas for reading nested json with json_normalize or read_json

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I have a `json object` with the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
json_data_raw = [{"indicator_value":{"195606": 
                                              {"2010":{"AFG": 0.29, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.607}, 
                                               "2011": {"AFG": 0.406, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.737}, 
                                               "2012": {"AFG": 0.345, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.587}, 
                                               "2013": {"AFG": 0.28, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.871}, 
                                               "2014": {"AFG": 0.253, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.88}, 
                                               "2015": {"AFG": 0.262, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.88}, 
                                               "2016": {"AFG": 0.245, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.77}, 
                                               "2017": {"AFG": 0.247, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.845}, 
                                               "2018": {"AFG": 0.254, 
                                                       "ZWE": 0.849}}}, 
                  "country_name": {"AFG": "Afghanistan", 
                                   "ZWE": "Zimbabwe"}, 
                  "indicator_name": {"195606": "Carbon dioxide emissions, production emissions per capita (tonnes)"}}]
```

When I try to read this structure with `pd.read_json` method I manage to load only the first node of the data, namely `"indicator_value"`, `"country_name"` and `"indicator_name"` with the nested instances only.

I tried also to use `pd.json_normalize` and no success neither since I don't quite get how to specify the parameters record_path or meta (metadata) contained in my `json object` and getting odd results.

Ideally I would like to get a table like this.
[image]

and so on for the other `country/year/values...`

Probably this is more than a single task and will involve other kind of object manipulation.
In any case I much appreciate some help.

Comment: Hey ruben, Could you post the desired result in table format? That makes it easier for other people to read your question.

Comment: In principle I wanted to add the desired table as an inserted image but apparently this was not allowed. They only give me the option of posting the link though :/
First post, you know... newby here. But thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly create a `variable` named `d`....basically it contains the inner `dictionary`

```
d=json_data_raw[0]
```

Now create a `dataframe df`:-

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(list(d.values())[0].values())[0])
```

so here `list(list(d.values())[0].values())[0]` have 3 level deeper `dictionary`

now,

```
df=df.stack().to_frame()
```

**Note:-**here you can overwrite `df` or create a new `variable`
the above code make a `multi index dataframe` so to remove `multi index` we use:-

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

now to rename columns:-

```
df.columns=['country_code','year','Carbon dioxide emssions,production emission per capita(tonnes)']
```

Now we will create a function that will change the country_code column to country name i.e

```
def country(val):
    if val=='AFG':
        return 'Afganistan'
    else:
        return 'Zimbabwe'
```

Now we will use `apply()` method

```
country=df['country_code'].apply(country)
```

Now finally we will insert the country column in our `dataframe df`

```
df.insert(0,'country_name',country)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output

**output:-**

```
    country_name    country_code    year    Carbon dioxide emssions,production emission per capita(tonnes)
0   Afganistan               AFG    2010    0.290
1   Afganistan               AFG    2011    0.406
2   Afganistan               AFG    2012    0.345
3   Afganistan               AFG    2013    0.280
4   Afganistan               AFG    2014    0.253
5   Afganistan               AFG    2015    0.262
6   Afganistan               AFG    2016    0.245
7   Afganistan               AFG    2017    0.247
8   Afganistan               AFG    2018    0.254
9   Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2010    0.607
10  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2011    0.737
11  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2012    0.587
12  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2013    0.871
13  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2014    0.880
14  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2015    0.880
15  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2016    0.770
16  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2017    0.845
17  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2018    0.849
```

**Note:-** well see I create a `function` because in your `json` object there are only 2 country and if you have country more than 2 and you have this same `json` format then the code **before** I define/create `function country()` work as it is.

but then instead of making `function` and then using `apply()` method
use this:-

```
countryinfo=list(json_data_raw[0].values())[1]
```

Now if you print `countryinfo` you get a `dictionary` in which `keys` are country code and its `values` are country name

Output of `countryinfo`:-

```
{'AFG': 'Afghanistan', 'ZWE': 'Zimbabwe'}
```

well by `list(json_data_raw[0].values())[1]` we are grabbing the data of `"country_name"` which is stored inside your `json object:- json_data_raw` and storing it in a `variable` named country info

so now

```
country=df['country_code'].replace(countryinfo.keys(),countryinfo.values())
```

so here basically we are replacing the value of `df['country_code']` with the values of `countryinfo dictionary` so it will returns a `Series` of values and we are storing that `Series` in `variable` named `country`

and finally no we `insert 'country_name'` column at `index 0` in our `dataframe df`

```
df.insert(0,'country_name',country)
```

Now if you print df then you will get your desired output regardless of number of countries you have in your `json_data_raw`

Output of `df`:-

```
    country_name    country_code    year    Carbon dioxide emssions,production emission per capita(tonnes)
0   Afganistan               AFG    2010    0.290
1   Afganistan               AFG    2011    0.406
2   Afganistan               AFG    2012    0.345
3   Afganistan               AFG    2013    0.280
4   Afganistan               AFG    2014    0.253
5   Afganistan               AFG    2015    0.262
6   Afganistan               AFG    2016    0.245
7   Afganistan               AFG    2017    0.247
8   Afganistan               AFG    2018    0.254
9   Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2010    0.607
10  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2011    0.737
11  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2012    0.587
12  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2013    0.871
13  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2014    0.880
14  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2015    0.880
15  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2016    0.770
16  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2017    0.845
17  Zimbabwe                 ZWE    2018    0.849
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot @anurag-dabas!!! plus the detailed explanation.

Comment: How would you generalize if you for instance don't know the number of countries @Anurag in your function that generates the country names?

Comment: @Ruben Lopez I added the answer of your question in my answer.....so just have a look